# where will android finish() return to

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, activity-finish

I have an activity than can be called from my parent activity and from other application via intent filter (i.e. ACTION_VIEW).

When I call finish() inside my activity, how to return to the correct caller?

i.e:
other application -> my activity -> finish() -> other application

currently if my main activity is still running, the finish() will return to my main activity, although it was called from other application.

Comment: ok, it's quite weird. if my activity is called by gmail app, it will return to gmail app when my activity finishes. but if it's called by dropbox app, it will return to my main activity when my activity finishes.

Comment: and my main activity's onActivityResult was not even fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on [Tasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) - by calling the activity from a different task (/application), you're bringing the existing Task to the foreground, which might include other Activities in the back stack that you don't want. I would suggest specifying the [android:taskAffinity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff) of the Activity that can be started from other Applications. Since this will ensure that this Activity will be the only one in the Task, it doesn't matter if it is started from within it's own app, or another.

EDIT: Figure 4 in the Tasks link shows your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. My app has several Intent filters for handling file (ACTION_VIEW, ACTION_SHARE). At the end of my processing part, I simply call finish(). For Gmail app via VIEW action, it will return correctly. For other apps via VIEW action, it won't return to the calling app. For other apps via SHARE action, it will return correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you start one activity with `startActivityForResult(Intent)` then you can get the second activity which started the first one with `getCallingActivity()`.

Comment: in this case, if my main activity is running. it was assumed that my main activity was the caller. but the original caller is actually other apps (i.e gmail, dropbox) who called my activity via ACTION_VIEW intent. So how to return to gmail/dropbox instead of my main activity.

Comment: So let me paraphrase your question: how to get the activity which started another activity from that started activity. I'm not sure if it's possible at all, at least you cannot extract such information from the intent.

Answer (score 1):

If you call the finish method on your activity, you will be returned to the topmost activity in the history stack. By default, it is the previous activity that you accessed.

For example:

Main > A > B

If finish is called on Activity B, you will return to Activity A.
If finish is called on Activity A, but Activity B is still alive, you will stay on Activity B since it is the topmost activity in your history stack.
If finish is called on Activity B, but for some reason Activity A is not in your history stack (most probably, if you specified that Activity A must not be saved in the history stack), you will return to Activity Main instead of Activity B.

Comment: could you elaborate more about history stack? how to debug the content of the stack? is the stack local to my app or global?

Comment: The history stack contains all the activities that you previously accessed. When you start a new activity, it will be pushed onto the history stack. Similarly, it will be popped from your history stack when you finished it. I think, on Android API 11, Android already have a built-support for manipulating the stack. I'm not sure if the stack is local to the app or not because I haven't tried calling an activity from one application to another yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use startactivityforresult() when you want to call the child activity. You'll return to the good one.